# How to get the expiration dates of all domains from a [MySQL] Plesk database?

Tags: mysql, plesk

I used to have this neat little report that ran on a dashboard I have for my daily stuff that would report on the expiration dates of all my hosted plesk domains [Plesk 9]

It looked like this:

```
select d.name, l.* from Limits l 
left join domains d on l.id =d.id 
where l.limit_name = "expiration" and d.name != ""
order by value
```

Very simple, I could just peek at it at the beginning of the month and the code I used to sort it and make human readable dates highlighted all the ones to be billed in the current month. Great.

I updated to Plesk 12, this is now broken as they seem to have changed the schema, for the life of me I can't seem to figure it out.

I've tried something like this:

```
select d.name, l.* from Limits l 
left join clients c on c.pool_id = l.id
left join domains d on c.id = d.cl_id 
where l.limit_name = "expiration" and d.name != ""
order by value ASC;
```

This does not seem to work either, just taking a sample of the results, a few domains show the expiration to be -1, but viewing them in Plesk show expiration dates. [expiration dates that match my last billing]

Does anyone know how to query the [MySQL] psa database to get a list of all domains expiration dates?

-thanks

**UPDATE**

Ok, a little more progress, by enabling & tailing the mysql query log I found these queries that will get the info I need:

```
select `id`, `name`, `displayName`, `cr_date`, `status`, `webspace_status`, `dns_zone_id`, `htype`, `cl_id`, `vendor_id`, `webspace_id`, `parentDomainId`, `cert_rep_id`, `real_size`, `guid`, `external_id`,
 `adminDescription`, `resellerDescription`, `description`, `overuse` from `domains` where `id`=110;


SELECT `Subscriptions`.* FROM `Subscriptions` AS `Subscriptions` WHERE (`object_type` = 'domain' AND `object_id` = 110);


SELECT `SubscriptionProperties`.* FROM `SubscriptionProperties` AS `SubscriptionProperties` WHERE (`subscription_id` = '70');


SELECT `Limits`.* FROM `Limits` AS `Limits` WHERE (`id` = '77');
```

The last little bit, id 77, comes from a limitsid value in the SubscriptionProperties table, how can I join all these queries into one so I can create a report? 
I'm working on something like this, but not making any headway:

```
select s.* , d.name, l.*
from Subscriptions s left join domains d on s.object_id = d.id
left join SubscriptionProperties sp on sp.subscription_id = s.id
left join Limits l on l.id = (select SubscriptionProperties.value from SubscriptionProperties where subscription_id = s.id and name = 'limistid');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

```
select d.`name`, l.* from SubscriptionProperties sp 
left join Subscriptions s on s.id = sp.subscription_id
left join domains d on d.id = s.object_id
left join Limits l on l.id = sp.value
where sp.`name` = 'limitsId' and l.limit_name = 'expiration'
order by value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like:

```
for i in `mysql -uadmin -p\`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow\` psa -Ns -e "select name from domains"`; do /usr/local/psa/bin/domain -i $i; done | grep -B4 -i expir
```

Comment: I have not tested your solution, it may work fine, but  I'm running the report from a replicated copy of the psa database [I run a nightly backup of the production environment to my development environment] & the plesk scripts/tools are not available.

Answer (score 0):

You can find expiration date for domains subscription ID in Limits table of psa database.